# Django template lists

Tags: django, templates

I am relatively new to Django and I have a simple problem. In my template I have:

```
{% for article in article_list %}
<li>
{% for author in article.authors.all %}
        {{ author.name }}, 
{% endfor %}
{{ article.title }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

What I want is to be able to iterate over the author.name but the last name should end with a period not a comma. Do I have to go back to the view to achieve this, or is there some simple way in the template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In templates, for loops have a `first` and `last` attribute, so you can do this:

```
{% for author in article.authors.all %}
  {{ author.name }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% else %}.{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's great. I will have to explore further what features are available in the templates. Thanks again.